# Folland Theorem 6.14, why $|f_n|\leq ||f||_\infty\chi_E$

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 6.14 of Folland's Real Analysis:

Theorem 6.14 Let $p$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents. Suppose that $g$ is a measurable function on $X$ such that $fg \in L^1$ for all $f$ in the space $\Sigma$ of simple functions that vanish outside a set of finite measure, and the quantity $$M_q(g) = \sup \left\{\left|\int fg \right|: f \in \sum \text{ and } \|f\|_p = 1 \right\}$$.is finite. Also, suppose either that $S_g={x:g(x)\neq 0}$ is $\sigma$-finite or that $\mu$ is semifinite. Then $g\in L^q$ and $M_q(g)=||g||_q$.

Definition of $||f||_\infty$: $||f_\infty||=\inf\{a\geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x)|>a\})=0\}$

The first part of the proof is:

First, we remark that if $f$ is a bounded measurable function that vanishes outside a set $E$ of finite measure and $||f||p=1$, then $|\int f g|\le M_q(g)$. Indeed, there is a sequence ${f_n}$ of simple functions such that $|f_n|\le |f|$ (in particular, $f_n$ vanishes outside $E$) and $f_n\to f$ a.e. Since $|f_n|\le ||f||_\infty \chi_E$ and $\chi_E g\in L^1$, by the dominated convergence theorem we have $|\int f g|=\lim |\int f_n g|\le M_q(g)$.

I don't understand why $|f_n|\leq ||f||_\infty \chi_E$. I can only see $|f_n|\leq ||f||_\infty \chi_E$ a.e., but not $|f_n|\leq ||f||_\infty \chi_E$ for all $x$, as by the definition of infinity norm, $||f||_\infty$ is a inf, then it is possible there exists a $x$, such that $||f||_\infty\chi_E\leq |f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|$

Comment: The inequality may not hold for every x, but this doesn’t matter, as measure zero sets don’t contribute to the Lebesgue integral: For the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem to hold you only need $f_n g$ to be almost everywhere dominated by an $L^1$ function.